# Black and white picture bad quality printing

Tags: windows-7, printing, printer

[image: Here]

Above is the picture that I want to print.

[image: photo]

As you can see from my poorly printed picture in the left and the results of the printer test that I ran in the right the results are good. It's not the printer I think.

I'm using Paint to print the picture with its original size and it looks perfect there.

[image: screenshot]

I tried changing my printer's settings, but it didn't help.

[image: settings]

Is there anything I can do to improve my printout quality?

Comment: If that's the actual size of your image, it's tiny.  At 300 DPI it would be under ⅓" [about 8mm] square.

Comment: It looks as though the image has been brightened, but it's not easy to see where. Have you tried printing from a different image program? I don't remember what was available in Win7, but you can always down-load the excellent [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/), and it's available in a [PortableApps version](https://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/gimp_portable).

Comment: @AFH, I used the default printing dialog to print the picture, but the result was the same. I think it has something to do with the driver's settings of the printer, but I don't know which.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the picture's file, but the picture is displayed perfectly in the editor though.

Comment: I don't know this printer driver, but the settings which may be applying unwanted "corrections" are `Color Management` and `ICM Method`: you might try other values for these settings. When I looked at your image with Gimp, I found a Gamma of around 2.0 gave a loss of detail similar to what you are seeing in printing. Note that your sample print is probably two-level, as opposed the grey-scale image you are trying to print: try doing a test print, which gives a multi-level output.

Comment: @AFH, thanks for your help. Would you please explain what those two-levels means?

Comment: Black and white.

Comment: @AFH, how would you make the output multi-level in GImp?

Comment: Your image is multi-level already: it is the text in your test print which is probably two-level.

Comment: Sorry, I am little bit confused. Any text is perfectly printed through any editor and it is only pictures that I have issues with. The picture of a cow's head was always brightened, so I decided to increase the gamma to 2.0 to compensate the loss and it worked, but when I did the same to the full picture and printed it (the head picture is just a part of a bigger picture that I cropped to decrease ink consumption while testing), it was totally pink for the first time and also a little bit blue for the second time, even though there was neither pink or blue color in it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I set very low DPI both in GIMP and Paint.NET, so that an A4 sheet at 100% scale in the editor would match its real life counterpart when it is attached to the monitor.

Creating A4 sheet from the GIMP's template works fine as it comes with 300 of DPI.